# OpenVPN connects but my public IP remains the same?

Tags: network, catalina, vpn

I just bought a new router that supports OpenVPN, which I enabled. I then downloaded the official OpenVPN client from openvpn.org and set it up.

Connecting to my router seems to work fine (that is, the client says I am connected) but when I check my IP using some "What's my IP"-service it doesn't report my home IP but instead still lists me as connected from my actual location/IP.

What's wrong? Do I need to do something more than just installing, configuring and connecting the OpenVPN client to make regular Mac applications use the VPN-route?

Comment: There should be a setting in the OpenVPN client regarding "route all traffic through VPN"

Comment: @nohillside Hmm, do I need something more than OpenVPN Connect?

Comment: Don't have my Mac nearby, need to check at home tonight.

Comment: I‘m using Tunnelblick to connect to my OpenVPN, it has an option to enforce all IPv4 traffic to use the VPN.